# Updating Slim via composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, slim

So I am currently using 2.* within my JSON composer file but when I try to change it to @dev to get the latest update Slim 3, I get an error on my application. "Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Slim' not found".

Why can my app no longer find the namespace of Slim?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just update a Slim 2 app to Slim 3 using composer.

Slim 3 is a lot different from Slim 2.

The Slim namespace is still there but the class isn't called Slim anymore. 
It's `\Slim\App`.

Read the docs at: http://slimframework.com/docs/ (for Slim 3) and you'll see that there are many many breaking changes.

Comment: I read a number of those but there isn't much to go on quite yet as it's still a WIP. So I changed it to \Slim\App and now receiving "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Slim\Exception\NotFoundException' with message 'Identifier "container" is not defined", did Slim remove their "DI container" or was that renamed too?

Comment: Most of Slim seem to have been rebuilt. It's using a different Router for example (and I think the API has changed a bit as well) and it's using Pimple as DI container. So, like I said, there are many many breaking changes. It's a new major release. It's not a drop-in replacement for Slim 2.